# Django Filter data from multiple Models

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Here I used 4 models one is base models another three are derived model derived from base models. I want to filter data between these three models in which reference id is common one. I add code below for your reference.

*models.py*

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models models.CharField(max_length=20)

class JSDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    visiblity = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class JSPersonal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    JS = models.ForeignKey(JSDetails, unique=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class JSSkills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    JS = models.ForeignKey(JSDetails, unique=True)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

*views.py*

```
def Result(request):
    skills = request.GET['skill']
    country = request.GET['country']
    query = Q(skill__icontains=skills )
    query1 = Q(country__icontains=country )
    query2 = Q(visiblity=True)
```

Here these two keywords(skills="python", country="USA") both get matches or either one get match with above four model. It display the result like name,skill and country.Please some help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Result(request):
    skills = request.GET['skill']
    country = request.GET['country']
    query_skills = Q(jsskills__skill__icontains=skills)
    query_country = Q(jspersonal__country__icontains=country)
    query_visibility = Q(jsdetails__visiblity=True)
    users = User.objects.filter(query_skills | query_country, query_visibility)
    return render_tor_response('sometemplate.html', {'users': users})
```

Then in the template you cycle over the `users` you have in the context.